# Do "resent" and "resend" have anything to do in common potentially?

Tags: word-meaning

resend means:

> send (a message, letter, package, etc.) again.

resent means:

> feel bitterness or indignation at (a circumstance, action, or person).

Is there any potential connection between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.
The 'emotional' [resent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resent) is via old French, resentir, from Latin re + sentir, meaning to feel.

The 'posted again' [resent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/send) [simple past tense of resend] is from Middle English, from Old English sendan; akin to Old High German sendan, to send.

If you want to avoid any potential confusion, even if normally context would be clear, you can hyphenate re-sent, in the 'posted again' meaning.

From comments: these words sound different too.
[I don't do phonetics, sorry]
The emotional 'resent' is ri**zent**
The postal is almost like two words, as though it was hyphenated in the mind even if not on paper - same emphasis on each half. ree sent.

Comment: Indeed, every few months in a professional context someone inevitably says "I resent that email -- did you get it?" and you wish they were among those who hyphenate :)

Comment: In general, I find Brits hyphenate more than Americans & this is one reason I tend to use them. It preserves clarity of meaning.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that the pronunciation is different, too. (At least it usually is in AmE.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - in BrE we'd say resent (feel bitterness or indignation at a circumstance, action, or person) with a short first 'e' like in 'ten' or even an 'i' like in 'prison' and the 's' like a 'z', so rehzent or rizent but re-sent (about an email) with the 'e' of 're' like 'ee' in 'bee' and emphasised,  and the 's' like in sack, said, same, etc.

Comment: Added to answer already. BrE, though idk as AmE is much different when just spelled out like that.